# good and reasonably cheap way of connecting glass and metal in a vacuum setup

Tags: vacuum, technology

Sorry for this very technical question, but we suffer from this problem at work and I do not know any other place to ask.

Its about a good and cheap way of connecting a glass tube with a metal tube in a vacuum setup. There are some solutions with gradually changing glass-materials in order to minimize the tension caused by the different heating-extensions of metal and glass. However they are rather expensive and we would prefer a cheap solution.

We found a promising image of possible connection, however there was no manufacturer and no name of the flange given.
http://b1online.de/public/vacuum.jpg

So does anyone of you recognize this type of flange? Or does anyone know where to ask such a question? What would you suggest as a connection between metal and glass in a vacuum setup?

Comment: This is a very good candidate for the [Experimental Physics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32588/experimental-or-applied-physics) if it ever gets off the ground.

Comment: @dmckee, What would stay with the physics.se then?

Comment: In the picture You liked here, there are in fact 4 different connectors for tubes. Which is the one You are interested in?

Comment: thanks for your comments. I am interested in the connector in the middle of the picture. That one with the black O-ring in it. This connector would be screwed to the left end of the tube-part shown directly above. How is this system called? I would very much appreciate hints :-)